# When sending over mongoose data to ejs file, the data is sent over as [object, object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the username the user has signed up with/logged in with from the mongo database, then send it over to the main dashboard file, however, when I register, the username place where it is supposed to show up is just `[Object, Object]`. I think it is because I haven't parsed the data (which I don't know how to do), since the username place should be `[ { _id: 5fb119fb320e384c14ee995f, username: '1' } ]`
My code (App.Js)

```
var test = User.find().select({ email: req.body.email }); // Selects the username from the email that has been inputted
res.render("dashboard", {year:year, username: test}) // Renders the file
```

Comment: I believe you want to run the query as `const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec(); res.render("dashboard", {year: year, username: user.username })`

Comment: @chridam when i tried this, it came with a syntax error.
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You haven't shown us the express middleware function from where you are calling these methods from. You need to wrap this in an async function, for example `app.get('/username', async function (req, res) { const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec(); res.render("dashboard", {year: year, username: user.username }); } );`

Answer (score 0):

As @chridam said, you are not `await`ing your database call, so all you get is an unresolved Promise.

You need to add `await`, which, as you noticed, requires to be inside an `async` function.

Next point, that's not how you query Mongo. `.find()` will select all documents in your database. And that's not how you use `.select()`. It is used to select only some fields in each document, like `.find().select("userName email")`, and you pass it a string, not an object. Read the doc!

But even then, you will be getting, not JSON data, but Mongoose objects.

Mongoose objects are not just plain data. They also have methods like `.save()`.

If you need only the data without the methods, use `.lean()` (and besides, it's faster because it doesn't create Mongoose objects :

```
const callDb = async () => {
    const test = await User.find({ email: req.body.email }).lean();
    res.render("dashboard", {year:year, username: test})
}

callDb();
```